# async until doesn't enter iteratee (async 3.0.1)

Tags: node.js, async.js

Iteratee of async.until function is never called

Tried with node.js 10.16.0, async 3.0.1 on Windows 10 (1809)

```
const async = require('async');
var counter = 0;

async.until(() => {
    console.log('here?')
    return (counter > 10)
}, (cb) => {
    console.log('not here?');
    counter++;
    cb()
}, () => {
    console.log('the end');
})
```

Terminal output

```
PS C:\Users\hofman\Desktop\Tools\GIT\test> node .
here?
PS C:\Users\hofman\Desktop\Tools\GIT\test>
```

Answer (score 0):

`test` parameter should be an asynchronous function, like this

```
const async = require('async');
var counter = 0;

async.until(async () => {
    console.log('here?')
    return (counter > 10)
}, (cb) => {
    console.log('not here?');
    counter++;
    cb()
}, () => {
    console.log('the end');
})
```

see documentation here: https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#until

or using normal Node style async function, like this

```
const async = require('async');
var counter = 0;

async.until((cb) => {
    console.log('here?')
    cb(null, counter > 10)
}, (cb) => {
    console.log('not here?');
    counter++;
    cb()
}, () => {
    console.log('the end');
})
```

And in version 2.x the `test` parameter was defined as a normal function
https://caolan.github.io/async/v2/docs.html#until

Here's the Changelog for v3.0:
https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes

> whilst, doWhilst, until and doUntil now have asynchronous test functions

Comment: yes, because they changed the type of the test function in version 3.0